# unable to add "GooglePlacePicker" on swift framework of cocoapod

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have written custom framework in swift and I want to use "GooglePlacePicker" as an dependency on cocoapods spec of that framework.

Below is the podsspec of the development pod.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
   s.name             = 'Framework'
   s.version          = '0.1.0'
   s.summary          = 'A short description of Framework.'
   # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
   s.frameworks = 'UIKit'
   s.dependency 'Firebase/Messaging'
   s.dependency 'GooglePlacePicker'
end
```

whenever I'm try to install cocoapods on sample application, I'm getting the error

**"The 'Pods-NFClient' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (*Pods/GooglePlacePicker/Frameworks/GooglePlacePicker.framework)"**

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289#issuecomment-313726321 ?

Comment: is there a solution.?

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289#issuecomment-232775634 or https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3289#issuecomment-313726321 ?